# drop down menu in a form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a drop down menu in my form. But the menu is not showing and when I view the source it gives the following error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  mysql_query(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Filename: views/trainingNeedsview.php

Line Number: 89

I'm using Codeigniter and jQuery.

my view code where I'm trying to show the menu is following.

```
       <div class="col userFormMinColWidh">
    <select name="training_id" size="3 multiple" style="align:bottom">
<?php
 
    $getType = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM training ORDER BY id");
    while($title = mysql_fetch_object($getType)){
        echo "<option value=\"{$id->id}\">{$title->title}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>  
</div>
</div>
```

`training_id` is a field where I want to put the obtained value from the drop down menu.
And id and title are the fields of training field from which a want to fecth from training field. I'm new to coding so a little help will be appreciated

Comment: Why aren't you using the framework's db class? And why are you placing a query inside the view?

Comment: Anyway, you're not connecting to the db

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because there is no server listening at the host name and port you entered.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Application->config->database.php` and put the connection details there. Then you will be able to run your query. But I would suggest to use the `active record` class instead.

Comment: This is nonsense; OP's not using the framework DB class, so setting the connection details there won't magically pass the parameters to any other function.